# How to create javascript code that changes the class attribute of the container to three different repeating classes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a cycle of html containers  that automatically generates a php program, I need a javascript code that changes the class="" attribute of the container to three different repeating classes (for example: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 etc.).

Here is my css and html code:

```css
.test {
background: red;
}.test1 {
background: blue;
}.test2 {
background: green;
}.test3 {
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">This container must have class="test1"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test2"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test3"</div>
<div class="test">From here the function need repeat so this container must have class="test1"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test2"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test3"</div>
```

I need an answer without the use of jquery

Note: I am a beginner in javascript so I have not been able to create any code that does something similar.

Comment: Hi! SO isn't a coding service. Please include a minimal reproducible example, including your html, expected result, and what you've tried.

Comment: Loop over all the elements with `forEach()` or `for`. Convert the loop index to an array index with `i % 3`. Use that element of an array of classes. Assign it with `element.classList.add()`.

Comment: @mykaf Thanks you for this reply, I have edited my post

Comment: Do it from the `php` side, or use CSS to style them with `.test:nth-child(3n+1){background:blue} .test:nth-child(3n+2){background:green} .test:nth-child(3n+3){background:yellow}`

Comment: @Barmar And can you give me a complete answer since I am a beginner in javascript and I don't understand very well what I should do

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli With css I can't since the containers quantity is infinity, and with php I can't so I can not use this language

Comment: Why can't you use php? You even said it's a php program. *With css I can't since the containers quantity is infinity*: I'm not quite following.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: The CSS method as pointed out by @GabrielePetrioli will definitely work - with as many `div`s as there are on your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the method [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), this returns a nodeList of the matches elements, and then, changes the class atribute with a for/forEach loop, somthing like this:

```js
let container = document.querySelectorAll(".test"); // Read about css selectors

container.forEach((element, currentIndex) => {
  const count = (currentIndex % 3) + 1;
  element.classList.add(`test${count}`);
});
```

```css
.test {
background: red;
}
.test1 {
background: blue;
}
.test2 {
background: green;
}
.test3 {
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">This container must have class="test1"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test2"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test3"</div>
<div class="test">From here the function need repeat so this container must have class="test1"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test2"</div>
<div class="test">This container must have class="test3"</div>
```

or using a global `count` variable:

```
let container = document.querySelectorAll(".test"); // Read about css selectors
let count = 0;

container.forEach((element, currentIndex) => {
  //Using count variable
  count = count + 1;
  if (count > 3) {
    count = 0;
  } else {
    element.classList.add(`test-${count}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `index`? Did you mean `currentIndex`? But it needs to cycle back to `test1`.

Comment: yes,  currentIndex, but, if you need to restar to test-1,create a variable outside of the loop and do something like this, 
let count = 0;
//loop 
count = count +1;
if (count >3){
 count =0
}else{element.setAttribute('class',`test-${count}`) }
 if you want i can put all the implementation on the answer

Comment: Put that in the answer, not a comment, since it's clearly stated in the question.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, but their class names start at 1. You'll need to adjust for that, too.

Comment: You can use modulus: `let count = currentIndex % 3 + 1;`

Comment: Now in the answer you can see the complete implementation and add the 
@Barmar solution

Comment: Use `element.classList.add()`, not `element.setAttribute('class')`. And why do you do it twice?